# NSIS - how to get the filename of the installer executable?

Tags: nsis

I've found two ways of getting the complete path of the installer file in a NSIS script:

1. System::Call 'kernel32::GetModuleFileNameA(i 0, t .R0, i 1024) i r1'
2. Using $EXEPATH (2.26+)

But I need only the filename, and not the complete path. How go get it? Is there an ExtractFileName() type function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`$EXEFILE`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.2.3) is what you want. It'll be of the form `foo.exe`.